# Running speedlm on weighted data with missing values

Tags: r, speedglm

I am trying to run a linear regression on weighted data.
When using `speedlm` i get an error msg when there are missing values in the data.

```
 library(speedglm)
 sampleData <- data.frame(w = round(runif(12,0,1)),
                          target = rnorm(12,100,50),
                          predictor = c(NA, rnorm(10, 40, 10),NA))

 summary(sampleData)
```

> ```
>        w              target          predictor    
>  Min.   :0.0000   Min.   : -3.381   Min.   :22.58  
>  1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.: 48.321   1st Qu.:30.45  
>  Median :1.0000   Median : 84.156   Median :37.09  
>  Mean   :0.5833   Mean   : 92.306   Mean   :35.03  
>  3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:119.891   3rd Qu.:41.96  
>  Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :223.896   Max.   :43.48  
>                                     NA's   :2
> ```

```
 #run linear regression without weights
 linearNoWeights <- lm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData)
 speedLinearNoWeights <- speedlm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData)

 #run linear regression with weights
 linearWithWeights <- lm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData, weights =sampleData[,"w"] )
 speedLinearWithWheights <- speedlm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData, weights =sampleData[,"w"] )
```

> ```
> Error in base::crossprod(x, y) : non-conformable arguments
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In sqw * X :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> 2: In sqw * y :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> Called from: base::crossprod(x, y)
> ```

Is there any way around this that does not force me to fix the data before running the regression?

Comment: Why are you opposed to removing these two observations from the dataset prior to fitting the model?

Comment: @Roland what I showed here is an example I have actually many data frames and the NA's are important for the rest of the calculations

Answer (score 1):

You should try to change the `na.action` option. Below is your code, which I am able to run, when I change `na.action` to `na.exclude/na.omit`.

```
library(speedglm)
sampleData <- data.frame(w = round(runif(12,0,1)),
                         target = rnorm(12,100,50),
                         predictor = c(NA, rnorm(10, 40, 10),NA))
summary(sampleData)

linearNoWeights <- lm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData)
speedLinearNoWeights <- speedlm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData)

options(na.action="na.exclude") # or "na.omit"

linearNoWeights <- lm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData)
    speedLinearNoWeights <- speedlm(formula("target~predictor"), data = sampleData)
```

You can go through the documentation for `na.omit` or `na.exclude` to understand when to use what. Hope this helps.